# I am unable to publish post on user facebook wall using Spring Social

Tags: spring-social-facebook

I am successfully logged with my app using Spring Social Facebook. But i am unable to post on user Facebook wall. I got below error

POST request for "https://graph.facebook.com/197550980606288/feed" resulted in 403 (Forbidden); invoking error handler 
{"error":{"message":"(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action","type":"OAuthException","code":200,"fbtrace_id":"DQHUBlkYCOo"}}
2016-03-07 11:03:17,040 - ERROR [qtp696479026-23] - coach - Exception Occurred while posting a link on facebook for user Id : {}, exception is : {} 
org.springframework.social.InsufficientPermissionException: Insufficient permission for this operation.
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:120)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:65)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:566)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:524)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:495)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:343)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.publish(FacebookTemplate.java:266)
    at com.viprasi.web.controller.FacebookController.postOnWall(FacebookController.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)